# Unable to retrieve my DS160 Form even after entering the correct Application ID

Tags: visas, usa

I am trying to retrieve my DS160 Application but after going to the site `"Consular Electronic Application Center"` and entering the Application ID, it mentions `"No matching data found"`

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you so much!

Comment: They're deleted after 30 days of inactivity. Otherwise you should contact customer support